# Man page for jdk commands like jshell, jlink

Tags: java, manpage

On ubuntu, I have installed java doc via command:

> sudo apt install openjdk-11-doc

But, still can't find any doc via `man jlink`.

Does that means javadoc doesn't include man page for `jlink` or I didn't install it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a release, but from the package for *focal* or 20.04

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openjdk-11-doc

You can see the list of files or

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/openjdk-11-doc/filelist

Where I'll only provide the initial few lines

```
/usr/share/doc-base/openjdk-11-jdk-doc
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/api
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/copyright
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/index.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/legal
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/resources
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-doc/specs
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/allclasses-index.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/allclasses.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/allpackages-index.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/constant-values.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/deprecated-list.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/element-list
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/help-doc.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-1.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-10.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-11.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-12.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-13.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-14.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-15.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-16.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-17.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-18.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-19.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-2.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-20.html
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/index-files/index-21.html
```

(*etc; it's a long list!*)

The documentation found in that package is HTML viewable from a browser.

Comment: I can see both `/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/jdk.jlink/` and `/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/jdk.jshell` dirs on my local machine, but still javadoc doesn't show any things for `man jlink` or `man jshell`, guess that's not part of the man page ?

Comment: Sorry I don't use jdk/jre so have never looked at the packages. It's up to the packager to include `man` pages or not.  eg. the `man` page for `ls` is provided in the package that installs it (ie. look up the file list for https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/coreutils and you'll see `man` pages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/coreutils/filelist) for `ls` and other commands found in that package).